# Magento 2 layout xml is not working

Tags: magento2, layout, page-layouts, render-blocking

I am creating page layout using xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <container name="page.container.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page-container-main" before="-">
        <block name="page.container.h2" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<h2>Page List</div>]]></argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>

<referenceContainer name="page.container.main">
    <container name="page.container.info" htmlTag="section" htmlClass="page-lists" after="page.container.h2">
        <block name="page.container.text" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="text" xsi:type="string">Simple Text</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

I want to display page output in div `page-container-main` show `h2` tag and after show `text` in but current output is

```
<div class="page-container-main">
    <h2>Page List</h2>
</div>
<section class="page-lists">Simple Text</section>
```

As shown 'Simple Text' `section` is rendering out of `page-container-main` div but what i am actually expecting is below

```
<div class="page-container-main">
    <h2>Page List</h2>
    <section class="page-lists">Simple Text</section>
</div>
```

Comment: add this <?xml version="1.0"?> starting of your xml

Comment: @DharmendraJadav it is just a reference code, i have did in my system code